# iOS14 UIDatePicker has an offset

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uidatepicker

Adding a UIDatePicker and running it on iPhone SE2 or iPhone 8, has an offset on the right side.

This is the code used to add the UIDatePicker

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.inline
    datePicker.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(datePicker)
    datePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

And This iOS how it looks on iPhone SE2 and iPhone 11 (notice the cutoff on the right side of the iPhone SE2)

[image]

Anyone have this issue? any fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve that by adding layout anchors to the leading and trailing of your date picker:

```
    datePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(datePicker)

    datePicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,
                                    constant: 0).isActive=true
    datePicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,
                                        constant: 0).isActive=true
    datePicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,
                                         constant: 0).isActive=true
```

Comment: I tried using "NSLayoutConstraint.activate" with top, leading, trailing and height constraint and it did not work at first. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If this answer solved your problem you should accept it.